# Exporting map layout from QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am trying to write a processing script that takes a template file as input and writes out the current canvas content as a PDF. The processing script works fine. But when I use the script in a model, the map output is blank.

The model starts with a blank canvas. A layer is generated by the model and loaded in the canvas. Following that step the algorithm containing the script is called to generate the pdf. I have also set the previous step of the model as the parent, but no luck.

Below is the processing script.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsLayout, QgsLayoutExporter, QgsReadWriteContext, QgsMapSettings, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination, QgsProcessingParameterFile
from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument

class ExportLayoutAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """Saves the attributes of a vector layer to a CSV file."""
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    INPUT = 'INPUT'

    def flags(self):
          return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading


    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFile(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Template File'),
            )
        )

        # We add a file output of type CSV.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output File'),
                'PDF File (*.pdf)',
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, 'INPUT', context)
        pdf = self.parameterAsFileOutput(parameters, 'OUTPUT', context)
        # Load template from file
        p = context.project()
        l = QgsLayout(p)
        l.initializeDefaults()

        with open(source) as f:
            template_content = f.read()
        doc = QDomDocument()
        doc.setContent(template_content)

        # adding to existing items
        items, ok = l.loadFromTemplate(doc, QgsReadWriteContext(), False)
        title = l.itemById('Title')
        title.setText('My Map')
        map = l.itemById('Map')

        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(l)
        exporter.exportToPdf(
             pdf, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())

        return {'OUTPUT': pdf}

    def name(self):
        return 'export_layout'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Export Layout As PDF')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr(self.groupId())

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExportLayoutAlgorithm()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding a vector layer input to the script and adding it to the project from the script itself before exporting the layout.

```
layer = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, 'LAYER', context)
p = context.project()
p.addMapLayer(layer)
```

Now this script can be used inside a model where it takes the styled vector layer generated in the previous step as an input 'LAYER' and renders a PDF.